# Need help figuring out why this LUKS setup isn't working

Tags: arch-linux, grub, luks, mkinitcpio, raid0

Problem: I'm trying to set up an encrypted raid0 device with btrfs. I'm able to get beyond the first password prompt to enter the LUKS device but after that I get an error from fsck saying something like device UUID=187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98 not found.

I've been messing with it for about 12 hours now and I cant figure it out. I made sure to run grub-mkconfig before I reboot. Let me know if you need anymore info

```
$ blkid -o full
/dev/mapper/zion: LABEL="root" UUID="187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98" UUID_SUB="6cd2134e-5817-455a-a216-c41ce0495e63" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs"                                                                                                                      /dev/sdc2: UUID="30786a7f-df33-4f36-8c80-4a4f7b4e145d" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="07f3b77e-02" 

# /etc/crypttab                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             zion            UUID="30786a7f-df33-4f36-8c80-4a4f7b4e145d"     none            luks  

# /etc/fstab
UUID=187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98       /               btrfs           rw,relatime,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/     0 0

# /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
HOOKS=(base udev keyboard autodetect modconf block mdadm_udev encrypt fsck btrfs filesystems fsck)

# /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Arch"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos usb usb_keyboard ohci uhci ehci" 
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y 
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=y 
# other default values omitted

# /etc/mdadm.conf
ARRAY /dev/md/imsm0 metadata=imsm UUID=2c9194b5:2dc765c7:deb29150:22b74163                                                                                                                                                                                                     ARRAY /dev/md/zion_0 container=/dev/md/imsm0 member=0 UUID=533a48be:25fa4cb7:4111a783:7d68bb14 

$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-zen
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux-zen.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot:  initramfs-linux-zen-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot:  initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Detecting snapshots ...                     

# /boot/grub/grub.cfg

#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod part_msdos
insmod usb
insmod usb_keyboard
insmod ohci
insmod uhci
insmod ehci
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod cryptodisk
insmod luks
insmod gcry_rijndael
insmod gcry_rijndael
insmod gcry_sha256
insmod btrfs
cryptomount -u 30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d
set root='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'  187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_input console usb_keyboard
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Arch Linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod cryptodisk
    insmod luks
    insmod gcry_rijndael
    insmod gcry_rijndael
    insmod gcry_sha256
    insmod btrfs
    cryptomount -u 30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d
    set root='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'  187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux linux-zen ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux-zen root=UUID=187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98 rw  loglevel=3 quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux-zen.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Arch Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98' {
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux-zen' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-zen-advanced-187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod cryptodisk
        insmod luks
        insmod gcry_rijndael
        insmod gcry_rijndael
        insmod gcry_sha256
        insmod btrfs
        cryptomount -u 30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d
        set root='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'  187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux linux-zen ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux-zen root=UUID=187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98 rw  loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux-zen.img
    }
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux-zen (fallback initramfs)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-zen-fallback-187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod cryptodisk
        insmod luks
        insmod gcry_rijndael
        insmod gcry_rijndael
        insmod gcry_sha256
        insmod btrfs
        cryptomount -u 30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d
        set root='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'  187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux linux-zen ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux-zen root=UUID=187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98 rw  loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux-zen-fallback.img
    }
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-advanced-187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod cryptodisk
        insmod luks
        insmod gcry_rijndael
        insmod gcry_rijndael
        insmod gcry_sha256
        insmod btrfs
        cryptomount -u 30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d
        set root='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'  187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98 rw  loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux.img
    }
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux (fallback initramfs)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-fallback-187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod cryptodisk
        insmod luks
        insmod gcry_rijndael
        insmod gcry_rijndael
        insmod gcry_sha256
        insmod btrfs
        cryptomount -u 30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d
        set root='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='cryptouuid/30786a7fdf334f368c804a4f7b4e145d'  187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=187a468c-cab5-4a29-861e-8c5b2c7cca98 rw  loglevel=3 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_snapshots-btrfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/41_snapshots-btrfs ###
```

Comment: Does the raid assemble at all? Otherwise it could be wrong order of hooks, btrfs hook running too early.

Comment: Does GRUB generate the [cryptdevice](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#cryptdevice) parameter? Can you post the generated `grub.cfg`?

Comment: I added grub.cfg to the post. I also changed the order of the mkinitcpio HOOK value. I added fsck before the btrfs and moved btrfs after encryption hook just to see if it made a difference

Comment: cryptdevice for encrypt seems to be missing (see also `mkinitcpio -H encrypt`)